# Expand the select List: Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Requirement: Display the select list underneath both textboxes on key press.

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-field-wk3ndp?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code you sent as an example, style it like this:

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  width: 200% !important;
}

.dropdown-menu#basic-example2{
  right: 0 !important;
  left: unset !important;
}
```